# Spring WS error on define two endpoint with same Namespace and localPart

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, soap, spring-ws

i'm trying to update a project and merge two different module into one. I actually have to define a Spring WS with two @Endpoint which map same @PayloadRoot but they're invoke by different endpoint but i get an error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Cannot map endpoint [..omissis..] on registration key [..omissis..]: there's already endpoint [..omissis..] mapped
```

**EndpointA:**

```
@Endpoint
public class EndpointA {
        private static final String NAMESPACE_URI = "http://example.com";
    
        @PayloadRoot(namespace = NAMESPACE_URI, localPart = "sendSomething")
        @ResponsePayload
        public Response sendSomething(@RequestPayload Request message) {
        methodA();
        }
```

**EndpointB:**

```
@Endpoint
public class EndpointB {
        private static final String NAMESPACE_URI = "http://example.com";
    
        @PayloadRoot(namespace = NAMESPACE_URI, localPart = "sendSomething")
        @ResponsePayload
        public Response sendSomething(@RequestPayload Request message) {
        methodB();
        }
```

**WebService**:

```
@EnableWs
@Configuration
public class WebServiceConfig extends WsConfigurerAdapter {


    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean<MessageDispatcherServlet> messageDispatcherServlet(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        MessageDispatcherServlet servlet = new MessageDispatcherServlet();
        servlet.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
        servlet.setTransformWsdlLocations(true);
        return new ServletRegistrationBean<>(servlet,"/endpointA/services/*","/endpointB/services/*");
    }
```

How can i relate with this configuration without changing WSDL definition?

**UPDATE #1:**

After [M.Denium](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2696260/m-deinum) help i've tried to register two endpoint separately with two applicationContext like this:

```
import ...

//@EnableWs
@Configuration
public class WebServiceConfig extends WsConfigurationSupport {

   @Override
    public void addInterceptors(List<EndpointInterceptor> interceptors) {
       interceptors.add(new EndpointInterceptor());
    }

    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean<MessageDispatcherServlet> messageDispatcherServletA(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext annotationConfigApplicationContext=new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();

        annotationConfigApplicationContext.register(EndpointA.class);
        annotationConfigApplicationContext.setParent(applicationContext);
        annotationConfigApplicationContext.refresh();
        
        
        MessageDispatcherServlet servlet = new MessageDispatcherServlet(annotationConfigApplicationContext);
        servlet.setTransformWsdlLocations(true);

        return new ServletRegistrationBean<>(servlet,"/clientA/services/*");
    }

    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean<MessageDispatcherServlet> messageDispatcherServletB(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext annotationConfigApplicationContext=new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        annotationConfigApplicationContext.register(EndpointB.class);
        annotationConfigApplicationContext.setParent(applicationContext);
        annotationConfigApplicationContext.refresh();
        MessageDispatcherServlet servlet = new MessageDispatcherServlet(annotationConfigApplicationContext);
        servlet.setTransformWsdlLocations(true);

        return new ServletRegistrationBean<>(servlet,"/clientB/services/*");
    }
```

And excluding this class from component-scan:

```
ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.example",excludeFilters = {@ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE,value = EndpointA.class),@ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE,value = EndpointB.class)})
public class ExampleApplication {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(ExampleApplication.class, args);
}
```

}

But i'm getting an error:

```
|| WARN  | EndpointNotFound.dispatch:237 | No endpoint mapping found for [SaajSoapMessage
```

I've tried without splitting applicationContext and removing exclude two endpoint and it worked (obviously with only one @Endpoint annotation). Am I making some mistakes?

Comment: You cannot. You can only create 2 servlets, map them to different urls and have only 1 endpoint in each. But isn't it a bit strange that the same wsdl/contract leads to different operations?

Comment: How can i manage to implements your solution? i know that is a little bit strange and i have to face with custom definition of request/response because same WSDL contract was used with different end-user. I cannot ask them to change their implementations

Comment: I would say it isn't strange but just wrong, but alas. As stated create 2 `MessageDispatcherServlet` instances, each registered to a different URL, and each only containing an application context with 1 endpoint.

Comment: Hello, i was trying to implements your solution but i cannot manage to register an endpoint to a specific context. Could you please provide a draft of solution? Thanks in advice!

Comment: Disable component-scanning (or at least exclude these 2 beans from being detected, using an exclude rule) and explicitly register the endpoint explicitly with a newly constructed application context.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I try your solution and i update post with new info. Could you please check and let me know if i am making some kind of mistakes with servletConfig?

Comment: You need 2 configuration classes, each with an `@EnableWs` to get all the necessary beans. Because you need 2 the auto-configuration of that won't work as it will try to detect the endpoints in the parent (as that is where it is now probably enabled) and not the correct context. So a config class with `@EnableWs` and register that next to your endpoint. That way you should have everything in-place for this.

Comment: I do as you said but it doesn't work. I created two clone class one for each endpoint but same as i posted with @EnableWS and put endpoint into same package with @Endpoint annotation. Do i have to enable  `@ComponentScan` on class with `@EnableWS` annotation? If i do this, there's conflict on endpoint and without i get usual error "No Endpoint found".

Comment: No you have to make sure that each servlet has the configuration loaded (and exclude it from the main configuration).

Comment: You could also create 2 configuration classes each with an `@Bean` for exposing the `@Endpoint` instead of registering it like you do now.